# How to iterate over just one key in an array of hashes in Ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

Complete ruby noob trying to build projects to practice. My aim here is to create a recipe converter which can take user input to form an array of hashes, and then converts the portion size of the recipe.

Each hash is one ingredient with the following keys: quantity, metric, ingredient (so: 500 g butter => {quantity: 500, metric: g, ingredient: butter}). This is so I can manipulate the various parts of the ingredients eg. convert portion sizes, or oz to g (later). This example deals with the easiest manipulation - portion size i.e changing recipe quantities.

Here's the code which takes user input and generates the array of hashes:

```
puts "Please enter your recipe. Press X when done." 
puts "Enter ingredient"

recipe = []
ingredient = "default"
metric = "g"
quantity = 1

def create_ingredient(quantity, metric, ingredient)
    {
        quantity: quantity,
        metric: metric,
        ingredient: ingredient
    }
end

loop do 
    ingredient = gets.chomp.capitalize 
        if ingredient == "X"
        break loop
        end
    puts "Enter metric"
        metric = gets.chomp.downcase
    puts "Enter quantity"
        quantity = gets.chomp

    recipe.push(create_ingredient(quantity, metric, ingredient))    
    puts "Enter another ingredient, if done press X"

end

puts recipe
```

I kept getting name errors until I put the default values at the top but this part works. (any suggestions for cleaning up welcome!)

This is the converter:

```
#conversion code to change portion size
puts "How many portions is this recipe for?"
    orig_portion = gets.chomp.to_i
    Integer(orig_portion)
    unless (orig_portion.is_a?(Integer) == true)
        puts "Please enter a number"
        orig_portion = gets.chomp
    end
puts "How many people are you cooking for?"
    new_portion = gets.chomp.to_i
    Integer(new_portion)
    unless (new_portion.is_a?(Integer) == true)
        puts "Please enter a number"
        new_portion = gets.chomp
    end

#not working from here 

def convert_recipe(recipe)
    recipe.each do |key, value|
        puts "#{( ( value recipe["quantity".to_i] / orig_portion ) *new_portion )} #{recipe["metric"]} #{recipe["ingredient"]}"
    end
end

puts convert_recipe(recipe)
```

Right now, the code runs and generates the array of hashes, takes the portion input but then gives this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        3: from recipe calc2.rb:66:in `<main>'
        2: from recipe calc2.rb:61:in `convert_recipe'
        1: from recipe calc2.rb:61:in `each'
recipe calc2.rb:62:in `block in convert_recipe': undefined local variable or method `orig_portion' for main:Object (NameError)
```

I've tried a few suggestions from other stackoverflow answers on iterating over an array of hashes, some of which are incorporated here. I tried using `(quantity, **)` as the argument for the `convert_recipe` method but it raised a name error on the method.

I can't understand why I keep getting name errors when I've defined the variables or methods (as far as I can tell) so any help understanding these errors would be so useful.

Thanks a lot for any help or suggestions!

Comment: `orig_portion` is defined outside the `convert_recipe`, that way is inaccessible within the method. You could try passing it as an argument to `convert_recipe`.

Comment: `orig_portion = gets.chomp` will result in a string (you forgot the `.to_i`). Oh, and `to_i` will chomp the string, so you don't have to.

Comment: You should take some time to review _scope_ in Ruby, it determines how data is shared/accessible between different places

Comment: Methods, blocks, and a few other things create scope gates. You either need to pass-by-value between your methods when you call them, or create instance variables that can be shared within a class. You probably also want to define your ingredients as a Struct instead of a Hash returned by a method.

Comment: @SebastianPalma thank you that helped fix it in this code

Comment: @steenslag I corrected this too thank you!

Comment: @ToddA.Jacobs I've taken this route to learn more about data structures to be able to apply these ideas- thank you. This is the most helpful suggestion. My plan was to export this to a json database and parse when needed, but going to come back around to it after I've revised this.